# MySQL query to fetch any combination of exists/doesnt exist

Tags: jquery, mysql, sql, optimization

I have a table with 3 columns and millions of rows. all are integers (hashes)

`id, attribute, attrib_val`

id can have many rows with combinations of attribute names and values.

The table has two keys
`id, attribute, attrib_val
     attribute, attrib_val, id`

I need to build dynamically, queries that can fetch ids based on rules for example:

ids in which **all** sections below should match:

`attribute <x> contains value <y> or <t>
attribute <l> does not contain value <f> or <c>
...`

ids in which **any** of the sections below should match:

`attribute <x> contains value <y> or <t>
attribute <l> does not contain value <f> or <c>
...`

The problem:
This is the query I came up with (I can change to id NOT in for the does not contain parts and change the AND to OR to change from OR to ANY:

```
SELECT distinct id FROM attributes 
WHERE id IN (
  SELECT id FROM attributes 
  WHERE  ( (attribute = 12944489 AND attrib_value =  907348202 ) 
) 
AND id IN (
  SELECT  id FROM attributes 
  WHERE ( 
    (attribute = 577513892 AND attrib_val = 519655334 ) 
    OR (attribute = 577513892 AND attrib_val = 1266247963 ) 
  ) 
  )
)
```

The problem is that this query is not efficient.
For some reason Mysql scans all table rows altough if I run each subquery seperately it contains a few 100s of rows.

How can I optimize this query or come up with alternative one that can handle the flexible requirements efficiently.
Notes: 1. Mysql 5.5.31 2. I simplified the queries for easy explaining. in reality there is an additional global sid column and all queries include sid=XXX in each where segment.

Comment: Using joins is a LOT more efficient than using nested select statements.  I'd recommend starting there and seeing what improvements you get.

Comment: Don't use `IN ( SELECT ... )`, use `JOIN`.  A "self-join" in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using `group by` and `having`:

```
SELECT id
FROM attributes 
WHERE (attribute, attrib_value) IN ( (12944489, 907348202), (577513892, 519655334), (577513892, 1266247963) ) 
GROUP BY id 
HAVING SUM( (attribute, attrib_value) IN ( (12944489, 907348202) ) ) > 0 AND
       SUM( (attribute, attrib_value) IN ( (577513892, 519655334), (577513892, 1266247963) ) ) = 0;
```

Comment: thats a great solution Gordon, thanks,
Is there a way to do  attribute <l> does not contain value <f> or <c> (where there is no 'contains' part? I dont think that it will work because the WHERE part and HAVING part negate.

Comment: This is an inefficient solution since `WHERE (a,b) IN ((1,2), ...) does not optimize _at all_.  (It will be fine if the table is small enough so that table scan is OK.)

Comment: @RickJames . . . According to notes in the documentation, this was actually fixed in 5.7.3 (https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=31188).

Comment: @GordonLinoff - Thanks!  I missed that Changelog entry.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id
    FROM a AS a1
    WHERE attr = 11 AND val IN (22, 33)
      AND NOT EXISTS (
              SELECT 1 FROM a
                  WHERE id = a1.id
                    AND attr = 44
                    AND val IN (55, 66) )

PRIMARY KEY(id)   -- Is this already there?  If so, good for inner query
INDEX(attr, val, id)  -- needed for outer query
```